# Combobox binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My `ComboBox` does not get populated with data.

Class `Employee` set to `public`, has variables such as:

```
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Code on `UserControl`:

```
public IEnumerable<csEmployee> employeeList;
public ObservableCollection<csEmployee> _employeeSorted { get; set; }

public ucAddClient()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Establish connection
    var GetMyData = new DataAccess();
    //Get data by procedure
    employeeList = GetMyDataPV.ExecuteStoredProc<csEmployee>("procedure", new {KeyDate = Key_to_extract});
    employeeList = employeeList.Where(record => record.EmployeeLevelID > 300);
    _employeeSorted = new ObservableCollection<csEmployee>(employeeList.Where(record => record != null));

}
```

And WPF:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbAddManager"
          Foreground="#FF4D648B"
          FontSize="12"
          IsEditable="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding _employeeSorted}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
          PreviewKeyDown="cbAddManager_PreviewKeyDown"
          Width="200">
    
    <!--<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width ="50" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=", "/>
                <TextBlock Width ="50" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>-->
    
</ComboBox>
```

Do you have any idea, why `ComboBox`is not populated? When I do this in code (I add it in user control class) it gets data needed.
Im not sure if Im binding it correctly?

Comment: Either put  initialization `_employeeSorted` before the `InitializeComponent()` or do implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `_employeeSorted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you assign a new instance of a collection to your `_employeeSorted` property after `InitializeComponent`. At that time, the binding is already set up and does not get notified that you have updated the property from `null`, because you do not implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

There are multiple ways to solve the issue:

- Initialize the collection before `InitializeComponent` and work on this same collection if you intend to change it, using `Clear` and `Add` instead of creating a new instance on changes.
- Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and use it to notify changes to your property so that the bindings are updated the the changes are applied in the user interface, e.g.:

  ```
  public partial class MyUserControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     private ObservableCollection<csEmployee> _employeeSortedField;

     public ObservableCollection<csEmployee> _employeeSorted
     {
        get => _employeeSortedField;
        set
        {
           if (_employeeSortedField == value)
              return;

           _employeeSortedField = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
     }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
  }
  ```
- Expose a depenedency property for the collection instead and bind it to a collection in your view model that is passed as data context of the `UserControl`, thus moving the data access out it and separating the view from the business logic and data (recommended, see below *MVVM*).

Another issue might be that you do not set your data context to the `UserControl` itself in XAML (which is **not recommened** by the way, although it might solve your issue). In this case, the binding is unable to resolve the property at runtime (a binding error will be shown in the output window).

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourProject.YourControl"
             ...
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

As a note, it seems that you mix your business logic with your `UserControl` (view). Leverage [the MVVM design pattern](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx) to create view models and seprate both concerns instead. Furthermore, if you set the data context of your `UserControl` to itself, you break data context inheritance.

Comment: This actually had answered two more questions I've got later on :) 
Also it tells me that i have to buy some book on MVVM and XAML as i have much to learn. 
Thanks for helping a newbie :)